# Select records with nearest expiration date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm fairly new to Access.
I have the 'Inventory' table with `ID`, `ExprDate`, and `LOT` fields, with ID be duplicatable and LOT is an unique index.
Something like this:

```
ID      LOT   ExprDate
1001    A1    30/12/22
1001    B1    30/12/23
1002    A2    30/12/23
1002    B2    30/12/24
1003    A3    30/12/25
```

I'm trying to make a query where it select the unique IDs with the nearest ExprDate and return their LOT, like this:

```
ID      LOT   ExprDate
1001    A1    30/12/22
1002    A2    30/12/23
1003    A3    30/12/25
```

but so far nothing. (I should mention ExprDate is a future date)

I've tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM Inventory 
WHERE (((Inventory.Exp)=(SELECT MIN(Inventory.Exp) FROM Inventory)));
```

but it returns only one record with the nearest date.
I've also tried selecting min in the total row but it returns all records.

I assume there's a workaround with 2 queries, one selecting unique ID with multiple LOTs and dates, the second returning the LOT of the nearest date from the first one. But if there is a way, I would like to do it all in one query.

Thank you for reading and have a good day.

Comment: should this only include dates that are in future or also already expired ?

Comment: preferably both. But realistically they are all in the future

Comment: would be great if you add some sample data and expected data from query

Comment: I did. There are 2 pictures in the posts. They're imgur links. I'm sorry. I'm really not good at this..

Comment: Data should be text tables not images.

Comment: And as @HarshGundecha shows, more than one way to accomplish.

Comment: oh sorry i thought the question is closed when i clicked the duplicate question button. I followed the link you sent and done it. Thank a bunch @June7

Answer (score 1):

```
create table inventory
(
    id        int,
    lot       varchar(10),
    expr_date date
);


insert into inventory
values (1001, 'A1', '20-12-2023'::date),
       (1001, 'B1', '20-12-2025'::date),
       (1002, 'A2', '20-12-2024'::date),
       (1002, 'B2', '20-12-2020'::date),
       (1003, 'A3', '20-11-2023'::date);


select i1.*
from inventory i1
join (
    select id, min(expr_date) as expr_date
    from inventory
    group by id
) i2
on i1.id = i2.id and i1.expr_date = i2.expr_date;


-- output
-- id       lot     expr_date
-- --------------------------
-- 1001     A1      2023-12-20
-- 1002     B2      2020-12-20
-- 1003     A3      2023-11-20
```

**Note** - this is as tested on postgresql 12 but should be mostly compatible with other SQL DBMS as well.