# SQL - Display a descriptive field based a date field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables in Access:

Table 1 has id, first_name, and last_name 
Table 2 has city, date_recorded, and person_id

I'm trying run a query to display the first name, last name, and city for the earliest date.

I'm able to get to this with the following query, but all records are displayed when I try to add City to results.
How can I add City to the results, but still only have 1 row per person?

```
SELECT table1.first_name, table1.last_name, Min(table2.date_recorded) AS First_Occurrence
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.person_id
GROUP BY table1.first_name, table1.last_name
ORDER BY Min(table2.date_recorded);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Top n records per group sql in access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220690/top-n-records-per-group-sql-in-access) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67429285/select-records-with-nearest-expiration-date?noredirect=1#comment119360655_67429285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to select the city for a person with minimum date_recorded as below.

```
  select id, first_name,last_name, First_Occurrence , (select city from table2 where person_id=t.id and date_recorded=first_occurrence ) as city 
from
(
    SELECT t1.id, t1.first_name, t1.last_name, min(t2.date_recorded) AS First_Occurrence
    FROM table1 as t1 INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.person_id
    GROUP BY  t1.id,t1.first_name, t1.last_name
    order by min(t2.date_recorded) 
) t
```

Comment: Sorry I missed a comma. Please try it now.

Comment: Did you build tables in Access for testing query? I did. You should get same errors.

Comment: Nope. Now got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @June7 I have revised my answer.